# Macro no funciona al abrir la plantilla .dotm

Tags: vba

Estoy realizando una plantilla de **`word`** donde carga en el encabezado una imagen, un texto y otra imagen y en el pie de pagina introduce texto. Pues bien, si depuro desde el editor VB, funciona perfectamente, pero si abro la plantilla **`.dotm`** desde el explorador de archivos, no carga nada y el documento nuevo se queda en blanco.

El codigo VBA es el siguiente:

```
Option Explicit


Sub Document_Open()
AddImageToHeader
End Sub

Sub Document_New()
AddImageToHeader

End Sub

Sub AddImageToHeader()


Dim SrcePath As String
Dim SrcePath2 As String

SrcePath = "C:\Users\Su\Downloads\descarga.jpg"
SrcePath2 = "C:\Users\Su\Downloads\descarga2.jpg"


With ThisDocument.Sections.Item(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=SrcePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Left:=-10, Top:=-40, Width:=100, Height:=100
.Range.Collapse
.Range.InsertAfter ("Esto es una prueba") & vbCrLf & ("Con salto de linea")
.Range.Font.Size = 20
.Range.Font.Bold = True
.Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
.Range.Collapse
.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=SrcePath2, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Left:=400, Top:=-40, Width:=100, Height:=100

End With
 AddFooter

End Sub

Sub AddFooter()

With ThisDocument.Sections.Item(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
.Range.Text = "Nombre Empresa (Provincia)" & vbCrLf & "Domicilio social   C.P.00000" & vbCrLf & "Telefono: 000000000    Fax: 000000000"
.Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
.Range.Font.Size = 9
End With
End  Sub
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Para ejecutar tu macro automáticamente al abrir el archivo, tienes que llamar a tu macro desde Evento document. Open (Word). Mira este enlace: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/word.document.open

Comment: Quizá tengas las macros deshabilitadas? Si no tienes las macros habilitadas completamente, el evento no se ejecuta y cuando ya las habilitas no se dispara.

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida y por vuestra rápida contestación. He estado revisando lo que me habéis comentado y los eventos New y Open los tengo al inicio del código y las macros las tengo habilitadas. Si que, al abrir el documento también me carga todo perfectamente pero al hacer doble click en el .dotm y  crear un nuevo documento en base a la plantilla nada de nada, todo en blanco. Alguna idea mas? Acabo de meterme a descubrir vba y voy un poco loca con esto. Creo que ebe de ser algo de configuracion en Word o plantillas, porque en depuración y al llamar en evento Open funciona genial!

Comment: Pues ya ahí tengo dudas. Tu macro se ejecuta en `ThisDocument`, es decir, el documento de la propia plantilla. Cuando creas un documento nuevo sobre la propia plantilla, es otro documento diferente, así que quizás `ThisDocument`ya no te sirva. ¿has probado con `ActiveDocument` o algo similar?

Comment: Solucionado!! He cambiado ThisDocument por ActiveDocument y perfecto. Muchas gracias Elier!

Comment: me alegro  @Sami. He publicado la respuesta. Solo faltaría marcarla como correcta y así se cierra la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Al ser un documento nuevo basado en una plantilla, no se podía utilizar el objeto `ThisDocument`. Lo correcto era usar `ActiveDocument`, para hacer referencia al documento activo basado en la plantilla.

> **[Propiedad Application. ActiveDocument (Word)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/word.application.activedocument)**